# Is this phrase and its usage correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Well , I know what does "Call it a night" mean, but I wanted to know if I could say "call it a day". E.g I'm working on a project in my office. And suddenly my parents call me up, can I say "let's call it a day " here?

Comment: Yes you can: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day

Comment: Actually I've been hearing "Let's call it a day" more often than "let's call it a night".

Answer (score 0):

Call it a day and call it a night are both idioms. If you stop doing something for the rest of the day, you call it a day.  On the other hand, if you stop working for the rest of the night, you call it a night (The Free Dictionary). They are not interchangeable.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day